# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class bolts.AggregateException found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar

Tags: java, android, json, gradle, jar

Hi currently i am working on project including parse server,and after adding parse library to my project ,when i run it it shows this error ,Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class bolts.AggregateException found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.AndroidExecutors found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.AndroidExecutors$1 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.AndroidExecutors$UIThreadExecutor found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.BoltsExecutors found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.BoltsExecutors$1 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.CancellationToken found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.CancellationTokenRegistration found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.CancellationTokenSource found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.CancellationTokenSource$1 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Capture found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Continuation found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.ExecutorException found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$1 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$10 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$11 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$12 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$13 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$14 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$15 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$15$1 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$2 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$3 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$4 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$5 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$6 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$7 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$8 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$9 found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.Task$UnobservedExceptionHandler found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.TaskCompletionSource found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.UnobservedErrorNotifier found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.UnobservedTaskException found in modules jetified-bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and jetified-bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4-rc-2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: I mean doesnt it literally say in the bottom there it is incompatible with the current version of Gradle you are using?

Comment: i tried changing both parse's and gradle's version but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try excluding the duplicate modules?
I tried removing the extra from Parse SDK.

```
implementation ("com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:$parseVersion"){
    exclude group: 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android', module: 'bolts-tasks'
}

// for Google login/signup support (optional)
implementation ("com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:google:$parseVersion"){
    exclude group: 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android', module: 'bolts-tasks'
}

// for Facebook login/signup support (optional)
implementation ("com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:facebook:$parseVersion"){
    exclude group: 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android', module: 'bolts-tasks'
}

// for Twitter login/signup support (optional)
implementation ("com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:twitter:$parseVersion"){
    exclude group: 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android', module: 'bolts-tasks'
}

// for FCM Push support (optional)
implementation ("com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:$parseVersion"){
    exclude group: 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android', module: 'bolts-tasks'
}

// for Kotlin extensions support (optional)
implementation ("com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:ktx:$parseVersion"){
    exclude group: 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android', module: 'bolts-tasks'
}
```